# How do i devide bootstrap background container into 2 colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I'm using Twitter bootstrap to implement my project interface , But I'm facing a background problem and until now and i can't solve it ,

" How do i devide bootstrap background container into 2 colors " , I mean every 6 cols have a different color and the Fluid-background container will be the same of columns from left and right
Image below is describe what i want to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN38U.png

So hope to get some tips

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might give you a start.

I've added a `.bg-outer` around the `.container` and given it a background containing a linear gradient. The linear gradient goes from left to right and the start and endpoint are both set at 50% for both colors making it an abrupt color change. One issue might be that this color change occurs in the middle of a gutter, if you want you can fix that by adding a `background-color` on the 7th `.col-xs-1`.

For the background of the column contents I've added a `div` inside each `col-xs-1`, the `div` gets a `background-color` using either the class `.bg-left` or `.bg-right`. If you were to add the `background-color` directly on the `col-xs-1` it would also give the grid gutter this color, as Bootstrap uses padding to create the grid gutter.

```css
.bg-outer {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6B6FFF 50%, #2C00C8 50%);
}

.bg-left {
  background-color: #913EDD;
}

.bg-right {
  background-color: #3900AB;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bg-outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-left">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-left">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-left">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-left">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-left">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-left">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-right">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-right">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-right">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-right">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-right">col</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="bg-right">col</div></div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```